# Storing ip adresses efficiently, for faster lookups and insertions (proxy checking)

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, python-3.x

I'm writing a small Python 3 program that is supposed to be testing the validity of a large number of proxies and I want to reorganize data so I can quickly lookup IP, test it via curl, write into database whether it works and timestamp.

With about 50 000 rows, 'simple way' takes too long, thus I need some clever way of searching through IPs.

I'm new to SQL, but if I was do it in some programming language, I would make something like this:

```
| IP_BYTE1 | IP_BYTE2 | IP_BYTE3 | IP_BYTE4 | TIMESTAMP | WORKS |
```

and then search 'left to right'.

Can anyone help me with creation of such a table and algorithm for fast lookup/insertion?

Comment: Why split up the IP into bytes?

Comment: either store it as the complete string (50k rows is not that much) or store it as 32 bit unsigned int. in both cases check for giving it a key, if you filter by it.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to store them in a table using your favorite data type (varchar or int) and then build an index on them.

If you are looking for different types of IP addresses, then you might want to break them into separate pieces.  Are you generally looking at type D addresses?  Or do you need to also look at types A, B, and C?